# Yii2 and Dialog error: "The file or directory to be published does not exist: vendor/bower/bootstrap3-dialog"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2, dialog, kartik-v

I am trying to use the [yii2-dialog](https://packagist.org/packages/kartik-v/yii2-dialog) widget in this way:

```
echo Dialog::widget([
    'libName' => 'krajeeDialogCust',
    'useNative' => false
]);

echo Html::a(
    'Stackoverflow',
    'https://stackoverflow.com/',
    [
        'data-confirm' => 'Do you accept?',
    ]
);
```

But I get this error message:

> The file or directory to be published does not exist:
>   my-directory/vendor/bower/bootstrap3-dialog

The error message also shows:

> DialogBootstrapAsset::register($view);
>
> $this->registerAssets();
>
> 'libName' => 'krajeeDialogCust',

It works if I use this (but it doesn't use the widget):

```
'useNative' => true
```

The [documentation](https://demos.krajee.com/dialog) doesn't talk about my problem but the widget's author give a [solution](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-dialog/issues/25) that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it installing [bootstrap3-dialog](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap3-dialog):

```
sudo apt-get install npm
sudo npm install -g bower
bower install bootstrap-dialog
composer require kartik-v/yii2-dialog "@dev"
```